# PHP replace characters in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to replace quotes and others characters from a mysql result array, using `strtr()` function. But i got `Warning: strtr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` and null values.

Heres my code:

```
  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($list)){

    $string_filter = array(';'=>'','['=>'',']'=>'','{'=>'','}'=>'','"'=>'',"'"=>'');

    $data[$rows['id']] = strtr($rows,$string_filter);

  }
```

`$data` is an array that i want to remove/trim the characters specified in `$string_filter` array. Heres the content sample from  `$data`:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [user_id] => 204554 [name] => Rich [group] => PL [ai] => BA [image] => 204554-35849.jpg ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [user_id] => 124534 [name] => James [group] => SS [ai] => IT [image] => 123141-12312.jpg )...
```

Comment: Replace them with what? `strstr()` searches strings, I suspect you're looking for `str_replace()`.

Comment: In fact i want to remove this characters.

Comment: For the specified row? Or for `$rows`? Your code is confusing, for instance what is `$data`, and what do you expect your code to return?

Comment: For every row value inside the loop. ```$data``` is an array. I want my code to return an array with specified characters in ```$string_filter``` removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Question, are you sure these characters actually exist in your data? Because the characters you are trying to remove are the ones php will automatically append to an array when that array is viewed via the print_r function. To be precise this statement

```
print_r(array('key' => 'value'));
```

will output

```
Array([key] => value)
```

even tough there is no actual `[` or `]` present in the arrays data itself.

In any case this code snippet will clean the keys and values of your array:

```
$string_filter = array(';'=>'','['=>'',']'=>'','{'=>'','}'=>'','"'=>'',"'"=>'');
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($list)){    
    $cleanedrow = [];
    foreach($rows as $key => $value) {
        $cleanedrow[strtr($key, $string_filter)] = strtr($value, $string_filter);
    }
    $data[$rows['id']] = $cleanedrow;
}
```

Comment: Yes, chars like single quotes do exist in data...But your script solve the problem. Thanks =)